# Not Able TO Fetch Local Phone Contact name , Cell Number and Email addresses

Tags: android, contacts

In my Application i want to fetch and List out Contact name their Number and there Email addresses i tried but `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email` and `ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME` conflicts so not able to fetch kindly if possible provide me some code i tried following code

```
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, null);
    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(
                    cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                 Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                         ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
                         null, 
                         ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", 
                         new String[]{id}, null);
                 while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                     String phoneNo = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                     Toast.makeText(NativeContentProvider.this, "Name: " + name + ", Phone No: " + phoneNo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 } 
            pCur.close();
        }
        }
    }
    String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
    Cursor emailCur = cr.query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
            null,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
            new String[]{id}, null);
    while (emailCur.moveToNext()) {
        // This would allow you get several email addresses
            // if the email addresses were stored in an array
        String email = emailCur.getString(
                      emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
        String emailType = emailCur.getString(
                      emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE));

      System.out.println("Email " + email + " Email Type : " + emailType);
    }
    emailCur.close();
```

Comment: HI Please refer to following link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152442/how-to-get-contact-email-id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem with your code may be that what you want should be in two separate queries.

Querying for a list of email accounts or phone numbers uses constants like those in ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds, URI:ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI.

Querying for actual Contact attributes that are not lists like name will use constants like those in ContactsContract.Contacts, URI:based of data returned from Contacts.CONTENT_URI.

The information is not all stored in the same place, and that's probably why there can be conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

```
 switch (reqCode) {
        case (REQUEST_CODE_email):
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri contactData = data.getData();
                Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    String contactId = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                    String hasNumber = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));
                    String num = "";
                    if (Integer.valueOf(hasNumber) == 1) {
                        Cursor numbers = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId, null, null);
                        while (numbers.moveToNext()) {
                            num = numbers.getString(numbers.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID));
                            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Number=" + num, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            //asdasdasdsa
                            if(getEmail(num).isEmpty()){
                                Toast.makeText(this, "Email Not Found In That Contact Try Another", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            else {
                                edt_email_contact.setText("" + getEmail(num));
                            }                            }
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
         case (REQUEST_CODE_number):
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri contactData = data.getData();
                Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    String contactId = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                    String hasNumber = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));
                    String num = "";
                    if (Integer.valueOf(hasNumber) == 1) {
                        Cursor numbers = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId, null, null);
                        while (numbers.moveToNext()) {
                            num = numbers.getString(numbers.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Number=" + num, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                            edt_email_contact.setText("" + num);
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
            }

    }
```