# Query for fetching email from contacts in Android 5.0 ? Getting Crash

Tags: android, email, crash, android-contentprovider, android-5.0-lollipop

I am working in an application where I have to fetch contacts and its details from my device.

I am using below query to fetch email id from contacts.

```
Cursor emailCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,null, ContactsContract.Data._ID+ " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);
```

GETTING CRASH on this line.

The complete is as mentioned below:

```
​private void displayContacts() {

        ContentResolver cr = RegistrationScreen.this.getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {

            while (cur.moveToNext()) {

                System.out.println("has numebr"+(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))));

                if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {

                    Bean bean = new Bean();

                    String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data._ID));

                    String name = cur.getString(cur .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    String fnamename = cur.getString(cur    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DATA2));
                    String lnamename = cur.getString(cur    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DATA3));
                    System.out.println("FIRTSNAME AND LAST NAME"+fnamename+"-"+lnamename);

                    System.out.println("ContactId is="+id+"For name="+name);
                    // String isUserProfile =
                    // cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.IS_USER_PROFILE));
                    String photoUri = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI));

                    Bitmap my_btmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.pic);
                    String file_name =""; 
                    String file_Path="";
                    if (photoUri != null) {
                        Uri my_contact_Uri = Uri.parse(photoUri);
                        try {
                            file_name =SharedPref.getValue(RegistrationScreen.this, SharedPref.PREFERENCE_KEY_USER_ID)+"-"+
                                    SharedPref.getValue(RegistrationScreen.this, SharedPref.PREFERENCE_KEY_IEMI_NO)+"-"+getCurretntTimeStam()+".PNG";

                            my_btmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(RegistrationScreen.this.getContentResolver(),my_contact_Uri);

                            file_Path=storeImage(my_btmp, file_name);
                            bean.setFile_name(file_name);
                            bean.setFilePath(file_Path);
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        // InputStream photo_stream =
                        // ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(getActivity().getContentResolver(),my_contact_Uri);
                        // BufferedInputStream buf =new
                        // BufferedInputStream(photo_stream);
                        // my_btmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buf);

                    }

                Cursor phonecur = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,  ContactsContract.Data._ID
                            + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);



                    System.out.println("phone count"+phonecur.getCount());
                    if(phonecur.getCount()>0){
                        while (phonecur.moveToNext()) {
                            String phoneNo = phonecur.getString(phonecur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));


                            int type = phonecur.getInt(phonecur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
                            String customLabel = phonecur.getString(phonecur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LABEL));
                            CharSequence phoneType = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.getTypeLabel(RegistrationScreen.this.getResources(),
                                    type, customLabel);



                            tempArrayList.add(phoneNo);
                            labelArrayList.add(String.valueOf(phoneType));



                        }

                        Cursor emailCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,null, ContactsContract.Data._ID
                                + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);





                        String noteWhere = ContactsContract.Data._ID + " = ? AND "+ ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
                        String[] noteWhereParams = new String[] { id,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Note.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE };
                        Cursor noteCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null,  noteWhere, noteWhereParams, null);


                        String addrWhere = ContactsContract.Data._ID + " = ? AND "+ ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
                        String[] addrWhereParams = new String[] {id,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE };
                        Cursor addrCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null,
                                addrWhere, addrWhereParams, null);



                        String websiteWhere = ContactsContract.Data._ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";

                        String[] websiteWhereParams = new String[] { id,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Website.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE };

                        Cursor websiteCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null,
                                websiteWhere, websiteWhereParams, null);

                        Cursor connectionCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI,
                                new String[]{ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE},
                                ContactsContract.Data._ID +"=?",
                                new String[]{String.valueOf(id)},
                                null);

                        if (connectionCur != null && connectionCur.getCount() >0)
                        {
                            while (connectionCur.moveToNext()) {
                                String accountName = connectionCur.getString(connectionCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME));
                                String accountType = connectionCur.getString(connectionCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE));

                                if(accountType!=null)
                                {

                                    if(accountType.contains("whatsapp"))
                                    {
                                        connectionArrayList.add(accountType);

                                        //Toast.makeText(LoginScreen.this, "whatsapp == "+accountType, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                    else if(accountType.contains("google"))
                                    {

                                        connectionArrayList.add(accountType);



                                    }
                                    else if(accountType.contains("facebook"))
                                    {

                                        connectionArrayList.add(accountType);


                                    }
                                    else if(accountType.contains("twitter"))
                                    {
                                        connectionArrayList.add(accountType);


                                    }
                                    else if(accountType.contains("linkedin"))
                                    {
                                        connectionArrayList.add(accountType);

                                            }

                                }
                            }

                        }



                        String notes ="";

                        while (noteCur.moveToNext()) {

                            notes = noteCur
                                    .getString(noteCur
                                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Note.NOTE));


                        }
                        String address="";

                        while (addrCur.moveToNext()) {
                            String poBox = addrCur.getString(addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POBOX));
                            String street = addrCur.getString(addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.STREET));
                            String city = addrCur.getString(addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CITY));
                            String state = addrCur.getString(addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.REGION));
                            String postalCode = addrCur.getString(addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POSTCODE));
                            String country = addrCur.getString(addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.COUNTRY));
                            String type1 = addrCur.getString(addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE));


                            address = poBox + " " + street + " " + city + " "
                                    + state + " " + postalCode + " " + country + " " + type1;
                                }

                        String website="";
                        while (websiteCur.moveToNext()) {
                            website = websiteCur.getString(websiteCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Website.DATA1));


                        }


                        while (emailCur.moveToNext()) {
                            // to get the contact names
                            String nameemail = emailCur.getString(emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                            Log.e("Name :", nameemail);
                            String email = emailCur .getString(emailCur .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));

                            String emailTypeint = emailCur.getString(emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE)); 

                            String customemailLabel = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LABEL));
                            CharSequence emailType = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.getTypeLabel(RegistrationScreen.this.getResources(),
                                    Integer.parseInt(emailTypeint), customemailLabel);

                            if (email != null) {

                                emailArrayList.add(email);
                                emailTypeArrayList.add(String.valueOf(emailType));//convert 12 into type

                            }

                        }

                        emailCur.close();
                        noteCur.close();
                        addrCur.close();
                        websiteCur.close();
                        //emailCur.close();
                        connectionCur.close();

                        // bean.setContactpic(my_btmp);

                        // bean.setContactNumber(contactNumber);
                        nameArrayList.add(bean);
                    }
                }

            }
    }​
```

This is working in below O.S. Just getting crash in 5.0.2. Below are the crash logs.

```
02-03 12:18:29.913: E/AndroidRuntime(14969): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-9391
02-03 12:18:29.913: E/AndroidRuntime(14969): Process: tv.w, PID: 14969
02-03 12:18:29.913: E/AndroidRuntime(14969): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unable to open database file (code 14)
02-03 12:18:29.913: E/AndroidRuntime(14969):    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:181)
02-03 12:18:29.913: E/AndroidRuntime(14969):    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:137)
02-03 12:18:29.913: E/AndroidRuntime(14969):    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:420)
02-03 12:18:29.913: E/AndroidRuntime(14969):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:478)
02-03 12:18:29.913: E/AndroidRuntime(14969):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:422)
02-03 12:18:29.913: E/AndroidRuntime(14969):    at tv.w.registration.RegistrationScreen.displayContacts(RegistrationScreen.java:859)
02-03 12:18:29.913: E/AndroidRuntime(14969):    at tv.w.registration.RegistrationScreen.access$3(RegistrationScreen.java:750)
02-03 12:18:29.913: E/AndroidRuntime(14969):    at tv.w.registration.RegistrationScreen$1$3.run(RegistrationScreen.java:410)
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this might Help you ... 
I have used this code its working fine.Check [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152442/how-to-get-contact-email-id) also if required

```
    public ArrayList<String> getNameEmailDetails(){
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null);
    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            Cursor cur1 = cr.query( 
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", 
                            new String[]{id}, null); 
            while (cur1.moveToNext()) { 
                //to get the contact names
                String name=cur1.getString(cur1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));

                String email = cur1.getString(cur1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));

                if(email!=null){
                    names.add(email);
                }
            } 
            cur1.close();
        }
    }
    return names;
}
```

Thanks,

Nayan

Comment: Please check the above source code. Its same what you have provided to me.

Comment: @Sam-In-TechValens  Hi, the above code works for Android 5.0~ 5.1 but doesn't work for Android M. Is there any change on contacts part for Android M?Thanks!!