# Unable to fetch contact names

Tags: android, android-listview, android-contacts

I am trying this code to retrieve the contact numbers and contact names. I got the numbers but the Names list returns null

```
ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver(); //Activity/Application android.content.Context
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        List<String> ContactNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        do
        {
            String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

            if(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0)
            {
                Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",new String[]{ id }, null);

                   while (pCur.moveToNext())
                {
                    String contactNumber = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    String contactNames = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    ContactNames.add(contactNames);
                    break;
                }
                pCur.close();
            }

        } while (cursor.moveToNext()) ;
    }
```

I don't know what I am missing. Please help

Comment: "String contactNames = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID));" what do you need CONTACT_ID for?

Comment: check this so question it has everything you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152442/how-to-get-contact-email-id

Comment: @KaranMer this will be extremely slow, if using with hundreds of contacts it can take a minute or more

Comment: @pskink sorry I updated it.. actually i was trying if it returns ANYTHING or not

Comment: but still a work around...@pskink will try and find better solution

Comment: @KaranMer compare it to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26820544/2252830

Comment: gonna try soon seems great piece of code. tnx @pskink for pointing out

Comment: @Prakhar see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26820544/2252830

Answer (score 0):

**Read Contact** List from **Phone**:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email;

public class ContactsUtils {

    public static ArrayList<ContactModel> getContactList(Context ctx) {

        ArrayList<ContactModel> list = new ArrayList<ContactModel>();
        String displayName = "", phoneNo = "", email = " ";
        ContentResolver contentResolver = ctx.getContentResolver();
        Cursor curMain = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        if (curMain.getCount() > 0) {
            while (curMain.moveToNext()) {
                String contactId = curMain.getString(curMain.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                displayName = curMain.getString(curMain.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                if (Integer.parseInt(curMain.getString(curMain.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                     Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",new String[]{contactId}, null);
                     contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID+ " = ?", new String[] { contactId }, null);
                     Cursor emailCursor = contentResolver.query(Email.CONTENT_URI, null,Email.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId, null, null);
                        if(emailCursor.getCount()>0){
                              while (emailCursor.moveToNext()) {
                                  email =   emailCursor.getString(emailCursor.getColumnIndex(Email.DATA));
                            }
                        }else{
                            email = "";
                        }
                        emailCursor.close();
                        if(phoneCursor.getCount()>0){
                              while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
                                  phoneNo = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                              }
                        }else{
                            phoneNo = "";
                        }
                      phoneCursor.close();

                    ContactModel cm = new ContactModel();
                    cm.setDisplayName(displayName);
                    cm.setPhoneNumber(phoneNo);
                    cm.setEmail(email);
                    list.add(cm);
                }
            }
        }
         curMain.close();
        return list;
    }

    public static class ContactModel implements Comparable<ContactModel>{
        private String displayName = "", phoneNumber = "", email = "";



        @Override
        public int compareTo(ContactModel another) {
            return getDisplayName().compareTo(another.getDisplayName());    
        }


        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }

        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }

        public String getDisplayName() {
            return displayName;
        }

        public void setDisplayName(String displayName) {
            this.displayName = displayName;
        }

        public String getPhoneNumber() {
            return phoneNumber;
        }

        public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
            this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        }


        public ContactModel() {
        }

        public ContactModel(String name) {
            this.displayName = name;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return displayName;
        }
    }
}
```

**Add permission** in **Manifest** file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: this will be extremely slow, if using with hundreds of contacts it can take a minute or more

Comment: @pskink, thanks for sharing concern, can we use AsyncTask task for the same ?

Comment: `AsyncTask` will not help: basically the algorithm is very slow, compare it to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26820544/2252830